# Good Way To Fetch / Display Large Data From Sql Query Using PHP (Fix Memory Limit)

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem which is maybe everyone has face it too. When creating report (basic html) then I'll code it like this :

```
<?php
  //Query String
  $query = "Select * from Table Where ... ";
  $sql = mssql_query($query);

  //Fetch it to array and display it on browser
  While($row=mssql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   //Display row in here $row[]
  }
?>
```

Using code above (with my understanding) data will be save into memory (array) before i choose what i'm gonna do with them (for example, display it on browser). If it is low data, then the script will be running well.

But when it goes to large amount of data, then it will be not working well because usually browser will display getting memory limit or in my case browser display nothing. I dont planning using paging to display large data. What i want to ask to all of you is, maybe someone of you know good way or trick to handle this.

Wish anyone would share solution or good way for this case.
Best regards

Comment: You can set a limit on the query and load more data by clicking on a link or with ajax.

Comment: I want display all of them. I don't planning using paging or limit  or etc..